# Equivalent of JavaScript non-strict comparisons in MongoDB queries

Tags: javascript, mongodb, comparison, equality

I'm confident this question must have been asked before but I couldn't find any reference to this topic.

I'm querying a MongoDB collection with the native JavaScript driver using data provided on a URL querystring as input, which therefore does not carry type information and is simply treated as a `String`.

The problem is, the data I'm trying to match against this input can be of a different type in the collection, for example a `Number` but I cannot predict this in advance. As far as I can see Mongo default comparison operators operate with strict semantics, so this query:

```
collection.find({ fieldName: value })
```

is equivalent to this JavaScript code:

```
fieldName === value
```

whereas I would like to apply non-strict semantics in this scenario (`==`), so that a value of `"123"` will match both `"123"` and `123`.

Does anyone know if this is possible without compromising the performance of the query?

Comment: Isn't it really easy in realty to standardise all your data input to strings?

Comment: Not necessarily, for instance if you're dealing with an existing data store. I am aware that there are workarounds, my question is whether this is possible with mongo (which you answered btw)

Comment: Indeed, yeah mongodb does not have a $lose operator currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, the data I'm trying to match against this input can be of a different type in the collection, for example a Number but I cannot predict this in advance.

If you can't normalise your values to a consistent type, you could always use the [`$in` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to find alternatives, eg:

```
db.test.find({ fieldName: { $in: [123, "123"]}})
```

An index on `fieldName` will include both numeric and string values.

One caveat to be aware of with mixed types is that sorting by that field may not work as you expect. Numbers and strings have different [Lexicographical Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), eg:

```
> db.test.find({}, {_id: 0, fieldName:1}).sort({fieldName:1})
{ "fieldName" : 123 }
{ "fieldName" : 456 }
{ "fieldName" : 1233 }
{ "fieldName" : 4566 }
{ "fieldName" : "123" }
{ "fieldName" : "1233" }
{ "fieldName" : "456" }
{ "fieldName" : "4566" }
```

Comment: I like this answer because its smart.  
But it requires to massage the req.query members in the server to add the non-quoted option.  
So I'll try my own solution, which is to have a list of numeric field names and "unquote" them.  
My case seems different as compared to the OP's in that I can tell which of my fields are numeric by name.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, the data I'm trying to match against this input can be of a different type in the collection, for example a Number

Sounds like a significant problem for most databases that implement some level of security through data types.

This can be a real problem if you don't account for it in MySQL, for example, where it does lose comparisons by default with no other setting.

Due to lose comparison you can actually return data that you either not supposed to or you don't want to (how else do you convert a string to an int?).

Anyway yes, this sounds like a proper problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

> but I cannot predict this in advance.

But you could standardise all your inputs to be string, no matter what. So even pure numbers go in as string if they are to be compared with strings.

That way no data type juggling is needed and you can query in a standardised manner.

Anyway,

> Does anyone know if this is possible without compromising the performance of the query?

No.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the OP, I can tell which fields in the collection are going to be numeric.
But I was facing the OP's same issue: the fields in the req.query objects are all strings.
So I make numbers out of them with this code snippet I want to share:

```
purchaseNumericfields = [ "component", "cook", "cost", "date", 
"_id","packSize", "price", "quantity", "supplier", "time", ];
const htmlQuery = { ...req.query };
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries( htmlQuery )) {
  if( purchaseNumericfields.includes( key )){
    htmlQuery[ key ] = Number( value );
  };
};
```

This should ensure that `Number()` does not return NaN over a rogue non-numeric field.